# Username is getting appended to From address while sending mail using Mailkit

Tags: email, .net-core, smtpclient, mailkit

I am using the following code for sending mail using `mailkit` in dot net core.

```
var message = new MimeMessage();

message.From.Add(new MailboxAddress("Joey Tribbiani", "noreply@localhost.com"));
message.To.Add(new MailboxAddress("Mrs. Chanandler Bong", "mymail@gmail.com"));
message.Subject = "How you doin'?";
message.Body = new TextPart("plain"){ Text = @"Hey" };

using (var client = new SmtpClient())
{
   client.Connect("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
   client.Authenticate("mymail@gmail.com", "mypassword");
   client.Send(message);
   client.Disconnect(true);
}
```

I am using `smtp client` which requires authentication.

Once i receive a mail, the FROM address in that mail is `mymail@gmail.com` which is the username used to connect to that host, but not `noreply@localhost.com` which is actual FROM address.
The other option is username gets appended to the actual FROM address.
Example- noreply@localhost.com[mailto:mymail@gmail.com] 
Can someone provide a solution to control this?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a problem with MailKit, it's simply a feature of GMail. This is an attempt by Google to prevent spoofing emails.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Is there any way that I can control without appending username.

Comment: Use a different smtp server.

Comment: I tried many times but it didn't work. Can you give the details of those?